# HttpServletRequest casting fails when running Camel outside of Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-camel, jetty

I need to implement a simple Http-Proxy in Camel, to log the remote IP addresses of the incoming WebService requests.

So I have my route defined:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:" + 8081 + "?matchOnUriPrefix=true&optionsEnabled=true")
  .streamCaching()
  .process(wiresharkInboundLogger)
  .to("jetty:http://localhost:" + 8080 + "?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

And i have my Processor "wiresharkInboundLogger":

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

  // HttpServletRequest
  HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);

  if (request == null) {
    LOG.warn("No HttpServletRequest available!");
  } else {
    LOG.info("Client IP: " + request.getRemoteAddr());
  }
}
```

This works like a charm when running inside Inttelij. As soon as I run the identical application outside of Intellij via console command ("java -jar my-camel-app.jar") the casting of the HttpServletRequest returns "**null**", when triggered by the same request from SOAP UI.

I've packaged the jar with the following maven-plugin:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>my.wireshark.Wireshark</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Any ideas what might cause that strange behaviour?

Comment: Be careful with making uber JARs as you can mess that up. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-a-big-uber-jar.html

Comment: Switched to maven-shade-plugin. No change. Still the casting of HttpServerletRequest returns null outside of Intellij.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shade plugin need to merge the META-INF entries. If not just one type converter registry is used but all type converter are needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions here:

1) There's an additional transformer required, to generate the right Manifest:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer">
</transformer>
```

2) Use appassembler-plugin instead, but this generates rather "fat" applications:
    http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-program-scripts.html